# MySQL query to treat a column as positive or negative depending on another value

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL structured the following way:

```
table1
------
userid  varchar(20)
type    varchar(20)
amount  integer
```

Where type can be `deposit` or `withdrawal`.

I want to perform a query on this table where I can get the net balance of sum of withdrawals - deposits for a given user.

Is this possible with MySQL or do I need to run two separate queries and do the subtraction in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

```
select sum(
          case type
          when 'deposit' then amount
          when 'withdrawal' then -amount
          end 
          ) as balance
from $table where userid = $id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perform something like this. Adjust table name and your type values. It will group per user total Deposit and Debit and give you a balance column.

```
SELECT userid, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN [type] = 'Deposit' THEN amount 
         ELSE 0 
       END) AS deposit, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN [type] = 'Debit' THEN amount 
         ELSE 0 
       END) AS debit, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN [type] = 'Deposit' THEN amount 
         ELSE amount * -1 
       END) AS Balance 
   FROM   tblaccount 
GROUP  BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries should be able to do this:

```
select 
   (select sum(amount) 
    from table1 
    where type='deposit' 
    and userid = 'user1'
   ) - 
   (select sum(amount) 
    from table1 
    where type='withdrawal' 
    and userid = 'user1') 
 as deposit_minus_withdrawls
```

or with a case statement.

```
SELECT userid, SUM( 
  CASE TYPE WHEN  'withdrawal'
  THEN amount
  ELSE 0 
  END ) - 
  SUM( 
  CASE TYPE WHEN  'deposit'
  THEN amount
  ELSE 0 
  END ) AS balance
FROM table1
GROUP BY userid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```